# Rank records with cross-table column division

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to write an SQL Query which brings ranked records based on the division of two derived values from columns in different tables. So, Table 1 has a Column A and Table 2 has a Column B with both tables having common `school_id`. The data in Table A looks like:

```
school_id | student_id | subject_id | marks
123         ABC          7Y8U         94
234         UHT          4Y8U         87
123         ABC          8P0F         49
567         FCV          5Q1U         70
```

The data in Table B looks like:

```
school_id | prize_amt
123         3000     
234         4700     
123         8210     
567         3200
```

The calculation I need to make is:

```
required_value = total marks per school per student / number of times that school is awarded
```

I need `n` records ranked on the basis of `required_value` in `DESC` order. I was able to write two queries for now:

- Select Distinct schools with corresponding maximum total marks in DESC order for a given student only
- Select the number of times that school has been awarded in DESC order

How do I get multiple records ranked on `required_value` defined above? The desired results will be:

```
school_id | required_value   
234         87     
123         71.50     
567         70
```

So, School with ID `123` has marks 94 + 49 = 143 and it has received an award 2 times, so its `required_value` value is 143/2 = 71.50.

Comment: Where did school_ids 891 and 901 come from? They aren't in the sample data

Comment: @Mureinik Just sample demonstration. Let me correct the same.

Comment: @ShubhamA. How do you get required_value. Can you put it in terms of your query? What is "Total marks per school per student"? I literally do not see how you can get 29.67 from school_id 234

Comment: Is it coincidental that there's a 1-1 correlation between the data in both tables?

Comment: The sample data you provided, doesn't seem to match the desired results. Please at least shows us how you calculate required_value for school_id 234, and school_id 123.

Comment: @FrankerZ Updated sample data and also added explanation how I calculated the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use two aggregate queries, one to sum the marks per school and one to count the awards, join them on the school id and divide the results:

```
SELECT   a.school_id, sum_marks / num_awards
FROM     (SELECT   school_id, SUM(marks) AS sum_marks
          FROM     a
          GROUP BY school_id) a
JOIN     (SELECT   school_id, COUNT(*) AS num_awards
          FROM     b
          GROUP BY school_id) b ON a.school_id = b.school_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     select tableA.school_id,
    (sum(marks)/(count(tableA .school_id) *1.00)) as required_value   
    from tableA inner join tableB on tableA.school_id =tableB.school_id             
    group by school_id 
    order by (sum(marks)/(count(tableA.school_id) *1.00)) desc
```

Comment: @shubham does it help ?

Comment: use tablename.column name as you both table same column name

Comment: Can you format it, so it doesn't look like a 7 year old threw up on her homework? This is actually the most efficient solution so far.

Comment: So, upon further digging, it seems while you're query luckily works for this sample data, adding an additional item in TableA (`(123, 'ABC', '7P0F', 32)`) breaks your query. See [my query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6e1af/2) vs [your query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6e1af/3) with the new dataset.

Comment: I really dislike whining  @FrankerZ

Comment: Is this whining? Your code was sloppy, and borderline unreadable. I also wanted to point out, that this query make break depending on the dataset (Yours luckly worked because TableA school ID's matched TableB school ID's), because of how INNER JOIN works, with your group by. If you want upvotes, I highly recommend you read this: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/

Comment: Still trying the query. Let me get back on how this workout.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with this query:

```
SELECT a.school_id, total_marks/COUNT(b.school_id) as required_value FROM (
  SELECT school_id, SUM(marks) AS total_marks
  FROM TableA
  GROUP BY school_id
) a
LEFT JOIN TableB b on a.school_id = b.school_id
GROUP BY a.school_id
ORDER BY required_value DESC
```

1st, make your original query to get the total marks, group by school:

```
SELECT school_id, SUM(marks) AS total_marks
FROM TableA
GROUP BY school_id
```

From there, it's a simple left join (To grab all the count of times the school was rewarded `COUNT(b.school_id)`), and then do some math!

See the **sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/842df4/3)**.

Now, onto performance. This does appear to be slightly more performant than @Mureinik's query above, as you're using 1 derived table instead of 2:

My query:
[image]

Mureink's Query:
[image]

For small datasets, this shouldn't matter too much, but when the dataset grows this query will gradually get slower.

Comment: That is a nice comparison as well. Thanks, let me try the query and get back with outputs.